# Mysql query with IN and if-subquery not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I'm making a query that behaves differently when an admin user uses it compared to when a regular user uses it (in a reporting environment).

When an admin views, I want the report to run over all users. When a regular user uses it, I want the query to only look at users working under the current user.

I'm trying to make 1 report, so 1 query, that combines both aspects. My guess was this:

```
SELECT * FROM datatable dt WHERE dt.user_id IN (
    IF (currentUserAdmin = 1, (SELECT id FROM user), (SELECT id FROM user WHERE working_under = currentUserID))
)
```

(please imagine that `currentUserAdmin` and `currentUserID` are parameters passed to the stored procedure containing the report query, and that `datatable` is actually some real table)

The problem is that mysql says "Subquery returns more than 1 row". Well, I'd say that's the whole idea, because I'm trying to use this with an `IN` clause.

What can I do to make this query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not join the tables ?

```
     SELECT dt.* ,user.id FROM datatable dt
     INNER JOIN user ON user.id = dt.user_id
     WHERE currentUserAdmin = 1
     Or working_under = currentUserID
```